# При загрузке файл сохраняется не полностью

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8L34OAt.jpg]

Это скрипт на стороне сервера, он отвечает за прием и сохранение файла в специальную директорию, все работает, файл появляется, НО, сохраняется только часть файла произвольной длины (не понял от чего это зависит)

```
fileitem=form['filename']
if fileitem.filename:
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    with open('./materials/' + fn, 'wb') as fl:fl.write(fileitem.file.read())
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully<br><a href="/cgi-bin/resources.py?action=show">Готово</a>'
```

Вот форма которая отправляет файл.

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/load_file.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filename">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Попробовал множество примеров из тех что нашел... и судя по всему эти примеры не работаю только у меня.

Comment: А зачем использовать чтение/запись файла. Проще же просто его скопировать или переместить.

Comment: А `form` это что откуда?